# Errror hd0 read .press any key to continue

Tags: 18.04, grub2, 20.04, hard-drive, grubrescue

Error to read outside hd0 press any key to continue ..after pressing any key it boot properly.i have updated grub installed 18.04 an order version still the issue is same.. i was using 20.04 more than 2 months i have seen this issue first time.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution just change place hdd sata cable from slot 0 to 1 in motherboard.
I worked i my case.